# How to use Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I need help knowing how to execute python commands/programs through Visual Studio Code (in HTML).  Usually I know you can do something like {{python script}} or something like that but I've had trouble getting something like that working.  If someone knows how to do it, I could really use this information (for my website where I want to run python commands etc)

Thanks, Michael

Comment: aren't you using one of python's numerous web frameworks?